# Limit string to eight characters and return it with asterisk

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a studentDto. I want to determine the number
of characters for LastName. If number of characters is greater
than 8, I want to return the last name of 8 characters with two asterisk thus
cutting off the other characters

e.g Abumadem**

Here is how I started.I am unable to get it to work. Can you please assist?

```
public class StudentDto
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            var checkLength = LastName.Length;
            string First8Chars = string.Empty;
            int count=0;
            List<char> storeStrings = new List<char>();

            if (checkLength > 8)
            {                        
                foreach (var c in LastName)
                {
                    storeStrings.Add(c);
                    if ()
                    {
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is new attempt and no luck yet.

```
public class StudentDto
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            var checkLength = LastName.Length;
            string First8Chars = string.Empty;

            if (checkLength > 8)
            {
                First8Chars = LastName.Substring(0, 7) + "**";
                return First8Chars;
            }                   
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into `String.Substring`

Comment: Let the library do more work for you. The string class has great methods to find the IndexOf or take a SubString. Something like 
LastName.Length > 8 : LastName.SubString(0,7) + "**" : LastName

Comment: You also seem to have a circual loop there when you call "var checkLength = LastName.Length;". It will execute the same get of LastName that it's currently in.. again and again.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment where you cant use the String class methods?

Comment: Can you show me some sample code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
string _backingFieldLastName;
public string LastName
{
    get
    {
        return _backingFieldLastName == null || backingFieldLastName.Length <=8 ? 
               _backingFieldLastName :
               _backingFieldLastName.Substring(0,8) +"**"; // second parameter of substring is count of chars from the start index (first parameter)
    }
    set
    {
       _backingFieldLastName = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant use library functions for some reason:

```
private string _lastName = "";

    public string LastName
    {
        get
            {
                var checkLength = _lastName.Length;
                string First8Chars = string.Empty;
                string storeStrings = "";

                if (checkLength > 8)
                {
                    foreach (var c in _lastName)
                    {
                        storeStrings += c;
                        if (storeStrings.Length == 8)
                        {
                            storeStrings += "**";
                            return storeStrings;
                        }
                    }

                }
                return storeStrings;
            }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }
```

One thing I noticed is your use of LastName in the LastName property getter, a big no no, its causing recursion and you probably are getting a stack overflow exception

This could be written more concise, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you

Comment: I am okay with library functions. That's fine. How do I do that?

Comment: Thanks Steve. Where is the proper place to put this rather than putting it in the getter. Maybe I could do this at the stored procedure level because I am using one.

Comment: What I meant was you are accessing the LastName property from within the LastName property which is recursive and would cause a stack overflow. thats why I changed it to a backed property by adding the string _lastName and using that.

Comment: Using any one of the more shorter versions below would be better than the example I posted, I posted that on the assumption you couldn't use library functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq way:

```
var lastname = "Abumademal";
var formatted = (new string(lastname.Take(8).ToArray())).PadRight(lastname.Length, '*');
// will yield "Abumadem**"
```

"Take 8 chars and create a new string from this array, then pad it with as many * as needed."

full implementation:

```
private string lastname;

public string LastName
{
    get
    {
        if (null == this.lastname)
        {
            return null;
        }

        char[] firsteight = this.lastname.Take(8).ToArray();
        string tmp = new string(firsteight);
        // padding this way wasn't the actual requirement ...
        string result = tmp.PadRight(this.lastname.Length, '*');
        return result;
    }

    set
    {
        this.lastname = value;
    }
}
```